# Можно ли объединить 2 запроса в один в этом примере

Tags: php, mysql, объединение

Вначале запрашиваем перечень идентификаторов меток для файла, потом необходимо по этим идентификаторам получить имена самих меток, после вывести имена на страницу.
К сожалению, кроме PHP, еще плохо разобрался в других необходимых языках, но мне кажется, что это можно выполнить одним запросом, подскажите чем оперировать?

```
$fileLabels = [];
// запрашиваем перечень меток для текущего файла
$query = "
          SELECT
                label_id
          FROM
                filelabels
          WHERE
                file_id = " . $_GET['id'];
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    while ($filelabels = $result->fetch_row()[0])
    {
        $labelIDs[] = $filelabels;
    }

    // запрашиваем данные о метках (имена меток) для файла
    $query = "
              SELECT
                    id,
                    name
              FROM
                    labels
              WHERE
                    id IN (" . implode(", ", $labelIDs) . ")
             ";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
    {
        while ($labels = $result->fetch_row())
        {
            $fileLabels[$labels[0]] = $labels[1];
        }
    }
    else
        echo $mysqli->error;
}
else
    echo $mysqli->error;
```

Comment: Вопрос уже много раз задавался. Поищите здесь (т.е. на ru.so) по `inner join` - вам он нужен. Грубо, будет так: `SELECT labels.id, labels.name FROM labels INNER JOIN filelabels ON filelabels.label_id = labels.id WHERE filelabels.file_id = YOUR_FILE_ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Эта операция в SQL называется JOIN ([описание в документации MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)), у нее есть несколько видов (от которых зависит, какие именно данные включаются в выборку), но, in a nutshell, она просто объединяет две таблицы:

```sql
 SELECT l.id, l.name
 FROM labels AS l
 INNER JOIN filelabels AS fl ON l.id = fl.label_id
 WHERE fl.file_id = :file_id
```

В данном случае будет сделана выборка, объединяющая строки таблиц `labels` и `filelabels` по совпадению `labels.id` и `filelabels.label_id`, после чего результирующия выборка будет отфильтрована по `filelables.file_id`.